# Limpeza do Buffer após getchar

Tags: c, buffer

Bom Dia,

Pretendia saber como poderei optimizar a limpeza do buffer ao utilizar a função getchar(), como exemplo seguem os seguintes códigos:

Consigo que o seguinte código tenha o output correcto utilizando a técnica de "espaçamento no scanf conforme demonstro:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 float salario, imposto = 0.0;
 char sexo;

 printf ("Introduza o Salário: ");
 scanf("%f",&salario);
 printf ("Introduza o sexo: ");
 scanf (" %c",&sexo);
 switch (sexo)
   {
     case 'f':
     case 'F': imposto = 0.10;
             break;
     case 'm':
     case 'M': imposto = 0.05;
              break;
   }

   printf("Imposto %.2f\n",salario*imposto);

   return 0;
}
```

No entanto não consigo executar correctamente o seguinte código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 float salario, imposto = 0.0;
 char sexo;

 printf ("Introduza o Salário: ");
 scanf("%f",&salario);
 printf ("Introduza o sexo: ");
 sexo = getchar();
 switch (sexo)
   {
     case 'f':
     case 'F': imposto = 0.10;
             break;
     case 'm':
     case 'M': imposto = 0.05;
              break;
   }

   printf("Imposto %.2f\n",salario*imposto);

   return 0;
}
```

Apresentando o seguinte Output sem me deixar introduzir o sexo:

> Introduza o Salário: 100 Introduza o sexo: Imposto 0.00

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`getchar()` não é uma boa opção para ler entrada do usuário.** 
A razão por trás disso é que a função irá retornar apenas o primeiro caractere do buffer de entrada (ou buffer do teclado).

Vejamos um exemplo: se você pressionar tecla **E** e em seguida a tecla **Enter** no teclado, o buffer armazenaria:

```
 ------------------------------------
| 'E' | '\n' |     |     |     |     |
 ------------------------------------
```

Neste momento, ao executar o código abaixo, a função `getchar()` consome apenas o primeiro elemento do buffer, deixando o restante intacto:

```
printf ("Introduza o sexo: ");
sexo = getchar();
```

Veja como ficaria o buffer do teclado após a função `getchar()` ser executada:

```
 ------------------------------------
| '\n' |     |     |     |     |     |
 ------------------------------------
```

O problema é que se o seu programa executasse a função `getchar()` novamente, e o usuário pressionasse outra tecla qualquer (como **F**, por exemplo), o novo dado seria inserido no final do buffer:

```
 ------------------------------------
| '\n' | 'F' |     |     |     |     |
 ------------------------------------
```

Sendo assim, a próxima execução de `getchar()` iria retornar o `\n` ao invés do **F**, e você ficaria com a impressão de que seu programa não funciona.

**Desta forma**, é extremamente necessário limpar o buffer de entrada após executar `getchar()` para que não sobre nada no buffer. É por isso que a resposta do **@mutley** é importante. Algumas pessoas podem ainda recomendar execução da função `fflush(stdin)` depois de `getchar()` mas isso é altamente inapropriado porque `fflush()` serve apenas para limpar um stream de saída. Utilizar ele em um stream de entrada como *stdin*, causa um comportamento indefinido (undefined behavior).

Como alternativa, recomenda-se a utilização de `fgets()` com *stdin*.

Comment: Por Curiosidade O Que Aconteceria Se Usássemos O getchar() Se O Buffer Estivesse Vazio.

Comment: O código iria parar, esperando uma entrada no teclado.

Comment: Nossa É Mesmo, Eu Sabia Disso E To Voando, Eu Uso Direto getchar() Pra Pausar asuashsuahusa

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar a seguinte linha, junto com os `includes` do código:

```
#DEFINE flush "while ( getchar() != '\n' );"
```

Com o código ficando assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#DEFINE flush "while ( getchar() != '\n' );"

int main()
{
  float salario, imposto = 0.0;
  char sexo;

  printf ("Introduza o Salário: ");
  scanf("%f",&salario);
  printf ("Introduza o sexo: ");
  flush;
  sexo = getchar();
  switch (sexo)
  {
    case 'f':
    case 'F': imposto = 0.10;
              break;
    case 'm':
    case 'M': imposto = 0.05;
              break;
  }

 printf("Imposto %.2f\n",salario*imposto);

 return 0;
}
```

E apesar de não ter lido, a fonte da minha resposta sugeriu você ler [esse link](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfc.html), [este link](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html) e mais [este link](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html).

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

A função que uso é parecida com a que o usuário [mutlei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/18243/mutlei) sugeriu.

```
void limpaBuffer(void){
    char c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

A diferença é que neste caso pode ser usada em um arquivo que tem que ser limpo até o fim, e não apenas quando a condição é `'\n'`.

Mas acredito que seja melhor aplicar uma função própria, pois as soluções nativas, `fflush()`, `__fpurge()` são dependentes das plataformas Windows e Linux, respectivamente. E isto pode causar problemas se você não tiver absoluta certeza onde seu programa irá rodar.

Comment: tem que ser `int c ` para uso com `EOF`

Comment: End of File. Final de arquivo é independente de tipo.

Comment: https://repl.it/@MateusSchroeder/Tipo-EOF (portanto não é independente de tipo), e no rascunho: §7.21.1 "which expands to an integer constant expression, with type int and a negative value, that is returned by several functions to indicate end-of-file, that is, no more input from a stream;" e essa outra questão aqui https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/197629

Answer (score 0):

Só inserir o \n no final da leitura do número que ele não ficará no buffer de entrada:

```
scanf("%f\n",&salario);
scanf ("%c",&sexo);
```

Comment: Na verdade, isso apenas irá pular uma linha após ter lido a entrada.

Comment: o que é exatamente o que ele precisa: ler o salario em uma linha e o sexo na outra.

Comment: O que eu quero dizer é, não vai mudar em nada o input.