# Código não executa um segundo " var = getchar(); " se um if for verdadeiro

Tags: c, if

Por qual razão o código abaixo não me permite preencher a variável 'ext' se a condição estabelecida foi aceita?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main(){
    char ext;
    char dif;

    dif = getchar();

    if(dif=='p'||dif=='P'){
        printf("\nVoce digitou %c",dif);
        ext = getchar();
        printf("\nVoce digitou %c",ext);
        printf("\nDONE");
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        printf("\nShame on you buddy");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

output :

```
P

Voce digitou P
Voce digitou

DONE
--------------------------------
```

Comment: Veja, por exemplo, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43691/limpeza-do-buffer-ap%c3%b3s-getchar

Comment: Essa pergunta é duplicada. Como apontado pelo usuário bruno o problema está na limpeza do buffer. Uma alternativa é utilizar scanf com um espaço antes do %. Por exemplo, na linha 11 teríamos :                      " scanf("--%c",&dif); ", em que -- representa um espaço. Isso limpa o buffer e permite preencher outras variáveis com outras entradas.