# Linguagem C, Está pulando a linha do Scanf ou do Getchar

Tags: c

Estou criando uma pagina de exemplos, e nela uso 1 linha de scanf e 2 de getchar, porém quando respondo o primeiro scanf, ela pula o segundo, e o terceiro funciona, eu li que é por conta do \n que também é lido e interpretado como reposta (enter) no próximo comando, então quando dou enter no primeiro scanf ele já responde o segundo que é o getchar, para o scanf vi que resolve colocando %*c, mas nesse caso resolve só o scanf, depois no getchar acontece o mesmo, oque daria para fazer ?, vi que tem como limpar o buffer, tentei alguns códigos aqui que vi mas não funcionaram.. (no exemplo a seguir eu não usei o %*c).

```
int main ()
{

  int inteiro;          
  float real;           
  char letra;           
  printf ("Digite sua idade: ");
  scanf ("%d", &inteiro);   
  printf ("%d", inteiro);

  printf ("\nDigite sua idade: ");
  scanf ("%f", &real);      
  printf ("%f", real);

  printf ("\nDigite uma letra: ");
  scanf (" %c", &letra);
  printf ("A letra que voce digitou foi : %c", letra);  

  printf ("\nDigite outra letra : ");
  letra = getchar ();
  printf ("A letra que voce digitou foi : %c ", letra);
  
  printf ("\nDigite outra letra : ");
  letra = getchar ();
  printf ("A letra que voce digitou foi : %c ", letra);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void limpaBuffer(void) {
    char c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n');
}
`     Já tentou essa função para limpar o buffer? [Veja essa pargunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43691/limpeza-do-buffer-ap%C3%B3s-getchar?)

Answer (score 2):

Da forma que está lendo a entrada do usuário atualmente (com `scanf`), na chamada seguinte para ler o caractere com `%c`, a quebra de linha ainda está no buffer por conta da leitura anterior. Então ocorre a saída:

```
Digite uma letra : A letra que voce digitou foi :
```

**Isso não acontece porque o input foi ignorado e sim porque o último caractere de `'\n'` (quebra de linha, quando o usuário aperta a tecla "enter") foi lido pela função `scanf` ao invés da entrada seguinte.** O mesmo acontece com `getchar`. A forma mais simples de corrigir o problema (porém não muito estável, como já percebeu) é de colocar um espaço antes, como fez na primeira leitura inserindo o valor na variável `letra`:

```
scanf (" %c", &letra);
```

Outra forma de fazer isso é limpar o buffer a cada leitura de input com `getchar`. Não é recomendado usar `fflush(stdin)` e pode ler sobre [nesta página em inglês](https://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1052863818&id=1043284351).

Uma forma de limpar o buffer seria fazer sua leitura verificando `EOF` (*End Of File*) e quebras de linha:

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

Dessa forma, enquanto os valores lidos forem diferentes de uma quebra de linha ou `EOF`, efetivamente ignoramos esses que "restaram" da última leitura. Na prática, teríamos algo como:

```
  printf("\nDigite sua idade: ");
  scanf("%f", &real);      
  printf("%f", real);
  while ((letra = getchar()) != '\n' && letra != EOF);

  printf("\nDigite uma letra: ");
  scanf("%c", &letra);
  printf("A letra que voce digitou foi: %c", letra);  
  while ((letra = getchar()) != '\n' && letra != EOF);

  printf("\nDigite outra letra: ");
  scanf("%c", &letra);
  printf("A letra que voce digitou foi: %c ", letra);
  while ((letra = getchar()) != '\n' && letra != EOF);
  
  printf("\nDigite outra letra: ");
  scanf("%c", &letra);
  printf("A letra que voce digitou foi: %c ", letra);
```

Não é necessário limpar o buffer antes de ler um número, dado que não será interpretado como `char` sem `casting` (como viu que não teve problemas ao ler os dois números iniciais durante a execução do programa).