# Por que ao digitar a operação o programa encerra?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    float A;
    float B;
    char Operacao[20];

    printf("Escreva o 1° valor : \n");
    scanf("%f", &A);
    printf("Escreva o 2° valor : \n");
    scanf("%f", &B);
    printf("Qual será a operação? \n");
    scanf("%c", &Operacao);

    if(Operacao == "Soma"){
        printf("O resultado da soma é : %.2f", A + B);
    }else{
        if(Operacao == "Subtração"){
            printf("O resultado da subtração é : %.2f", A - B);
        }else{
            if(Operacao == "Multiplicação"){
                printf("O resultado da Multiplicação é : %.2f", A * B);
            }else{ 
                if(Operacao == "Subtração"){
                    printf("O resultado da divisão é : %.2f", A / B);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Quando ele lê qual será a operação, o programa acaba, o que eu devo fazer?

[rogerio@archlabs ~]$ ./Calculadora

Escreva o 1° valor :

9

Escreva o 2° valor :

8

Qual será a operação?

[rogerio@archlabs ~]$

Answer (score 2):

Há alguns problemas com seu código:

O problema do seu programa não estar lendo a entrada da "operação" ocorre por um comportamento da função `scanf` que pode ser  entendido melhor lendo [este post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/527903/linguagem-c-est%c3%a1-pulando-a-linha-do-scanf-ou-do-getchar/527911#527911). Um código refatorado está no final desta resposta para que entenda melhor o mecanismo de "limpeza" do buffer de `STDOUT` em C.

Na linha em que lê a string de operação, você colocou `"%c"`. Essa formatação é usada para leitura de apenas um caractere. Para corrigir o problema, troque por `"%s"` (leitura de uma string; ou sequência de caracteres) e não passe o endereço de `Operacao`, dado que uma sequência de caracteres é um ponteiro (ou seja, já é um endereço):

```
scanf("%s", Operacao);
```

Na comparação das strings, C não vai comparar da maneira que é feito em outras linguagens de alto nível, então substitua:

```
if (Operacao == "Soma")
```

Pelo uso da função [strcmp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp):

```
strcmp(Operacao, "Soma")
```

E não se esqueça de incluir o arquivo onde a função está localizada:

```
#include <string.h>
```

No começo do seu arquivo.

Último problema é o fato da sua última comparação querer uma divisão e está verificando por `"Subtração"`:

```
    if(Operacao == "Subtração"){
        printf("O resultado da divisão é : %.2f", A / B);
    }
```

Um exemplo do código que colocou na pergunta refatorado seria:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    float A;
    float B;
    char Operacao[20];
    char ch;

    printf("Escreva o 1° valor : \n");
    scanf("%f", &A);
    
    printf("Escreva o 2° valor : \n");
    scanf("%f", &B);
    
    printf("Qual será a operação? \n");
    
    // Limpando o buffer para evitar que a função "scanf" leia
    // a quebra de linha do último input.
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);

    scanf("%s", Operacao);

    // Utilizando múltiplos "return" dentro das condições para evitar encadear
    // "ifs" ou "else ifs".
    if (strcmp("Soma", Operacao) == 0) {
        printf("O resultado da soma é : %.2f", A + B);
        return 0;
    }
    
    if (strcmp("Subtração", Operacao) == 0) {
        printf("O resultado da subtração é : %.2f", A - B);
        return 0;
    }
    
    if (strcmp("Multiplicação", Operacao) == 0) {
        printf("O resultado da Multiplicação é : %.2f", A * B);
        return 0;
    }
    
    if (strcmp("Divisão", Operacao) == 0) {
        printf("O resultado da divisão é : %.2f", A / B);
        return 0;
    }
    
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado :)