# Quando meu código em C retorna ao inicio ele pula a etapa de solicitar o primeiro nome do usuário

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    float kwh_mensal, kwh_placa, qtd_placas, kwp, pot_placa, pot_inversor, valor_projeto, ger_dimensionada;
    int op,op2;
    char nome[30],sobrenome[30];

inicio: printf("\n\t----------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("\t\t||BEM-VINDO(A) A SOLAR ENGENHARIA!||");
        printf("\n\t----------------------------------------------------\n");

        //Solicita o nome e sobrenome do usuário
        printf("\n\tDigite seu primeiro nome: ");
        gets(nome);
        printf("\n\n\tDigite seu sobrenome: ");
        gets(sobrenome);
        //Solicita o consumo mensal de energia
        printf("\n\n\tDigite o seu consumo de energia mensal em kwh: ");
        scanf("%f.2\n",&kwh_mensal);
    do{
        //Pede que informe a potência da placa
        printf("\n\n\tEscolha a potência de placa.");
        printf("\n\n\t[1] 330 W\n\n\t[2] 440 W\n\n\t[3] 540 W\n\t");
        scanf("%i",&op);

    switch(op){
        case 1:
            pot_placa = 330;
            printf("\n\t----------------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("\n\tVocê escolheu a potência de 330 W.\n");
        break;
        case 2:
             pot_placa = 440;
             printf("\n\t----------------------------------------------------\n");
             printf("\n\tVocê escolheu a potência de 440 W.\n");
        break;
        case 3:
             pot_placa = 540;
             printf("\n\t----------------------------------------------------\n");
             printf("\n\tVocê escolheu a potência de 540 W.\n");
        break;
        default:
             printf("\n\t----------------------------------------------------\n");
             printf("\tOpção inválida!\n");
             printf("\n\t----------------------------------------------------\n");
        break;
               }
    }while ((op != 1)&&(op !=2)&&(op != 3));

         //Declara as variáveis para os cálculos
         float valor_kwp = 4600;
         int hsp= 4;// hsp - horas plenas de sol

             kwh_placa = ceilf(pot_placa/1000 * hsp * 30); // kWh da placa escolhida
             qtd_placas = ceilf(kwh_mensal/kwh_placa);//Determina a quantidade de placas
             kwp = qtd_placas * pot_placa/1000;//Determina a geração de energia em quilowatt pico(kWp
             pot_inversor = kwp * 0.75;//Determina a Potência do inversor quilowatt(kW)
             valor_projeto = kwp * valor_kwp;//Determina o valor do projeto
             ger_dimensionada = qtd_placas*kwh_placa; // Geração do sistema

             //Imprime os resultados
             printf("\n\tProjeto do(a) Sr(a) %s %s\n",nome,sobrenome);
             printf("\n\tConsumo do cliente: %.0f kWh\n",kwh_mensal);
             printf("\n\tGeração de energia dimensionada: %.2f kWh\n",ger_dimensionada);
             printf("\n\tPotência instalada: %.2f kWp\n",kwp);
             printf("\n\tPlacas instaladas: %.0f placas de %.0f W\n",qtd_placas,pot_placa);
             printf("\n\tInversor: %.2f kW.\n",pot_inversor);
             printf("\n\t----------------------------------------------------\n");
             printf("\t\t  |Valor do projeto: R$ %.2f.|",valor_projeto);
             printf("\n\t----------------------------------------------------\n");
        do{
             printf("\n\t[1] Solicitar novo orçamento..\n\n\t[0]Sair.\n");
             scanf("%i",&op2);

            switch(op2){
                case 0:
                    printf("\nSaindo...");
                break;
                case 1:
                    system("cls");
                    goto inicio;
                break;
                default:
                    printf("\n\tOpção inválida!\n");
                break;
                        }
            }while(op2 != 0);
                return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O que está acontecendo é uma problema com o buffer.

O buffer é um local onde o sistema coloca tudo que foi digitado, incluindo o <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (`\n`). Todas as funções que pegam o que é digitado, retiram dele o que precisa. No entanto, cada função trata o buffer de forma diferente.

No caso o `scanf()` retira apenas o que foi informado para retirar. entao se o buffer tiver com `123z\n` e for informado para tirar apenas um numero inteiro (`%i`), o buffer vai ficar com o `\n` armazenado.

Já o `gets()` todo valor até o encontrar o `\n` e limpa o buffer. Mas se tiver apenas o `\n` no buffer, ele retorna vazio.

Uma maneira de evitar esse problema, é limpar o buffer quanto usa o `scanf()`, por exemplo. pode ser feito colocando o código abaixo, na linha seguinte ao `scanf()`

```
scanf("%*[^\n]");scanf("%*c");
```

Pode ver uma explicação melhor [neste outro post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43691/limpeza-do-buffer-ap%C3%B3s-getchar) por exemplo.

Comment: O outro caso que possa usar é `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }`

Comment: @VagnerWentz não chega ser um neston , mas tem mesmo algumas formas de fazer :)

Comment: _"A função scanf() pega tudo que foi digitado e coloca no buffer"_ Não, não é isso. É bem o contrário. No modo normal de operação o **sistema** pega tudo que foi digitado até e incluindo o `ENTER` e coloca no buffer. `scanf()` retira o absoluto mínimo para satisfazer o pedido nos especificadores e retorna o total de especificadores atendidos. No caso aqui só tem um, `%f.2\n` na primeira chamada. O resto fica lá para ser lido depois. O programa não testou o retorno de `scanf()` o que é meio ingênuo, e não consumiu o ENTER que finalizou o primeiro `scanf()`

Comment: @arfneto realmente, minha explicação está errada. vou corrigir

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro encapsular a parte doo código onde pede o input do nome dentro de um while como o seguinte.

while ((getchar()) != '\n');

desta forma irá limpar o buffer que estará ocupado pela informação introduzida anteriormente e como tal irá ser solicitado o input novamente.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).